# Adding 'Next' and 'Previous' click overlays to horizontal scrolling gallery. And general gallery recommendations

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, gallery

Im currently building a simple horizontal scroll gallery for my website that features (near)full screen images. At the moment its just using html and css.

Here is an example build:
http:// blackecho.co.uk/test-scroll/scroll-gallery.html

(Sorry for the space in the link, can only post 2 links)

```css
#scroll_container{
  margin:0px;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  left:0;
  bottom:50px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

#scroll_images{
 height:100%; 
 overflow:none;
 white-space:nowrap;

}

.pic{
 height:98%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="scroll_container" >
        <div id="scroll_images">
         <img src="../assets/a.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/d.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/e.jpg" class="pic">
         <img src="../assets/10.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/9.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/1.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/0.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/2.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/3.jpg" class="pic">
            <img src="../assets/4.jpg" class="pic">
                        
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
 
 </div>
```

What I'm looking to accomplish is something visually the same as what I already have, but with the added feature of being able to click to the next and previous image relevant to what is currently on screen.
A perfect example would be like this: http://format.com/themes#panorama

I found a very similar post on here with a similar query: [Add Previous/Next Buttons to Horizontal Content Scroller Targeting DIVS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259387/add-previous-next-buttons-to-horizontal-content-scroller-targeting-divs) which resulted in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPF6F/26/). The main difference being, I don't want the prev/next buttons. I want it so the 2 halves of the screen correspond to the prev/next buttons like the example I linked to.

Apologies if this sounds confusing or long winded, but thank you in advance to anyone that can assist me or link me to some solutions. Or if anyone has some advice on a better way to produce what I already have it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily detect the mouse position with a jQuery listener.
Do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if ((e.pageX) <= (w/2)) {
          console.log("left");
          // code for changing the mouse cursor
          // ....
          // code for calling prev/next slide
          $(document).on("click", function(){
              // slide.next/prev
          });  
      } 
      else {
          console.log("right");
          // code for changing the mouse cursor
          // ....
          // code for calling prev/next slide
          $(document).on("click", function(){
              // slide.next/prev
          });
      }
    });

});
```

Code for changing the cursor:
[How to set a cursor image via jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389957/how-to-set-a-cursor-image-via-jquery)

================================ **EDIT** ===========================

The code i posted above works good as a general use but does not works smoothly with the gallery slider.

I did a quick refactoring of the code of the gallery to make it works. ( I have of course cut out some things for clarity).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // cache here reusable elements
    var container = $("#sg-scroll"),
        child = $(".sg-pic_wrap"),
        current;  

    // CURRENT ELEMENT CHECK
    function currentElem () {
        // .each() instead of for(i = 0; i < var;i++)
        child.each(function(){ 

            // these variables must  be updated each time
            // we launch the function, so we cache them inside 
            var x = $(this).offset().left, 
                w = $(this).width();

            if (x <= 0 && x < w ) {
                current = $(this);
            }
        })
    }

    // MOVE TO ELEM
    function scrollTo (elem) {
        container.scrollLeft(elem);
    }


    // CLICK
    container.on("click", function(e){
        var _w = $(window).width();
        if ((e.pageX) <= (_w/2)) { // LEFT
            // we only need to check the current element each time we click, not on scroll
            // doing this will result in faster js
            currentElem(); // 
                if (current.prev().length > 0) { // otherwise we get undefined error
                    scrollTo( parseInt((container.scrollLeft()) + (current.prev().offset().left) + 5) );
                }
        }
        else { // RIGHT
                currentElem();
                scrollTo( parseInt((container.scrollLeft()) + (current.next().offset().left) + 5) );
        }
    });


    // CURSOR ...
    container.on("mousemove", function(e){
        var _w = $(window).width();
        if ((e.pageX) <= (_w/2)) { // LEFT
            //change cursor here
        }
        else { // RIGHT
            // or here
        }
    });



});//document.ready
```

Updated jsfiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/naa4qwyk/7/

**note**
The above code works with a fullscreen-width gallery, and does not take in consideration browser resizes after dom.ready.
For completion one should add *window.load*  and *after-resize* events

========================== **EDIT 2 scroll to center** ==================

scroll to the center of the next/prev image:
First, change the currentElem function

```
function currentElem () {
    child.each(function(){

        var x = $(this).offset().left,
            w = $(this).width(),
            center = (container.width())/2;

        //if (x <= 0 && x < w ) {
          // current = $(this);
        //}
        if (x <= center && (x + w) >= center ) {
            current = $(this);
        }
    })
}
```

Then, the call to ScrollTo inside the click listener

```
var pos1 = ( (container.scrollLeft()) + (current.prev().offset().left)),
    pos2 = ( ((container.width()) - current.prev().width() )/2);
          scrollTo( parseInt( pos1 - pos2) +5 );
```

Yet another jsfiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/naa4qwyk/8/

Comment: Is it possible for you to help me incorporate it onto this: https://jsfiddle.net/naa4qwyk/3/ So I can essentially loose the next/prev buttons at the bottom and use the two left and right halves of the '#t-scroll' div as the overlaying buttons.

Comment: I have added your code to the bottom of this one (https://jsfiddle.net/naa4qwyk/4/) and changed/added code to get the curser change working.

Comment: Actually, is as simple as adding
`$("#sg-scroll").click(prev);` inside the if/else statement.
But the animation gets delayed because the next/prev function is not exactly performant.

Comment: There's probably a conflict with the mousemove listener. 
I will try to fix it or search a workaround.

Which makes me think: do you need to be able to click on the image? Otherwise it's as easy as adding two anchor html tags and style them with css so they take each half size the container.

Comment: No I don't need to click on the images. I did try a method of having two divs that took each of half of the container, the only issue I had with this is that it blocks the ability to scroll the containing div with a mouse-wheel.

Comment: I had my fingers on fire so i improved the code used for the gallery to make it work with the left/right checker.
With this you don't need the old js anymore. Just add the animations.
I posted it above as an edit. Let me know if it works. It should ;-)

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Ive accepted your answer as you gave me a solution to what I asked. Is it possible to get the element that is being scrolled to, to go to the center, as opposed to the left of the container. Here is an example of what I was working on with the old code: https://jsfiddle.net/naa4qwyk/6/. So far I only had the centering working on the 'next' button

Comment: If you like I can make it as a separate post so you get get more points for an answer?

Comment: That's kind of you but you should try to understand what's going on in the code and fix it to the center by yourself. That is, if you want to get better. I can help and explain what i did

Comment: I will have a look and see what I can do. I got pretty close to doing it on the old code, but one button wasn't working.

Comment: this:
`scrollTo( parseInt((container.scrollLeft()) + (current.prev().offset().left) + 5));`
is the code responsible for the movement. And the only thing you need to change.
It's just some math, you have to add to this code half the size of the current.prev() /next() element. Using the dev tools in your browser will help a lot

Comment: So far I added - (($("#sg-scroll").width() - current.prev().width()) / 2) where the +5 is, but it only works for the first image. I have to scroll the centred image to the left for it to become the current image. https://jsfiddle.net/bgjfe6u7/1/. I apologise for being so useless, I'm **very** inexperienced with java

Comment: It's never late to learn. your best friends are stack overflow, google, the browser dev tools and a nice good tutorial. And this is javascript/jquery, not java.

Comment: Ok, to center the element, quite a bit of code is needed, not just one line. You have to change the currentElem function to check when the item is centered and not when is at the left side of the container.
Not exactly difficult but takes some time.